# How to define "interior" for the unit arc?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry

Let the unit arc be,

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2| x_1^2 + x_2^2 =1, x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0\}$$

There is something I found curious about the unit arc which is that,

- It has an empty interior viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$
- It has an empty relative interior viewed as a subset of its affine
  hull, which is again a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and inherits the open
  balls.

But intuitively, the arc is not empty (everything in between the arc can be considered as an interior). Is there any way to define interior for these objects? (unit arc, embedded sphere in the orthant, etc)

Comment: Its inherited subspace topology.

Comment: Just use the relative topo... wait

Comment: My joke was the relative topology doesn't give a meaning to interior, which I suppose is what makes this question puzzling. But in the relative topology the subspace is not homogenous, and it's precisely the endpoints that look different, so e.g. the "interior" is just the largest submanifold.

Comment: As a 1 dimensional manifold.

Comment: The largest submanifold lacks the cross in that case (no nbhd is $R$-shaped). (But in that case I don't know what the interior should be.)

Comment: Can some one Who understand the question explain what the question is about? I fail to understand the question..

Comment: @VilleSalo Why its subspace topology does not give a meaning to the interior? I think I am not understanding this question...

Comment: @EFinat-S The issue with that is that *everything* counts as interior in that case. The OP wants to distinguish between the boundary points and the rest. Per Bjorn's answer, this can be done by paying attention to the (lack of) local Euclidean-ness. That said, I don't see how this question is appropriate for MO - it seems a much better fit for MSE.

Comment: As an aside, note that the interior can also be defined in terms of "typical behavior" *(assuming connectedness anyways; otherwise, work inside connected components separately)*. For example, $x\in Int(M)$ iff for every comeager $X\subseteq M$ there is some $y\in X$ and an autohomeomorphism of $M$ sending $x$ to $y$ iff for every subset $S\subseteq M$ which is a manifold of strictly lower dimension there is some $y\in M\setminus S$ and an autohomeomorphism of $M$ sending $x$ to $y$ iff [etc.].

Comment: @NoahSchweber it's the kind of question a grad student would ask, right? Not an undergraduate... so I feel like it's on topic here.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen My assessment was different. But perhaps I'm being overly negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems well described by the notion of interior $\mathrm{Int\ }M$ of a manifold with boundary $M$.

See the Wikipedia subentry [Manifold: Boundary and interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Boundary_and_interior).